# Flutter 2.0.0 Link Widget usage?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I was reading an [article](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-web-support-hits-the-stable-milestone-d6b84e83b425) regarding **Flutter Web 2.0.0**  updates, there I found [Link Widget](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/link/Link-class.html). I tried to use it in my widget tree like:

```
Link(
  uri: Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'),
  builder: (BuildContext context, FollowLink followLink) => ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: followLink,
    // ... other properties here ...
  )},
)
```

but it's showing an error:

> The element type 'Link' can't be assigned to the list type
> 'Widget'.dart(list_element_type_not_assignable)

How do I use it?

Comment: Where did You use it? In a Column?

Comment: Yeah but I tried it everywhere but it's not working anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably imported `Link` from `dart::io` by mistake. You need `url_launcher` as a dependency to use the `Link` widget.

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3  # or later :)
```

foobar.dart:

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Comment: I'll check that, but what actually it does??

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
    Link(
      uri: Uri.parse('https://flatteredwithflutter.com'),
      builder: (_, followLink) {
       return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: followLink,
        child: Text('Click me!!'),
     );
   },
    );
```

Good Luck ...